# How do I get the request params from a ESPAsyncWebServer?

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I currently have the following code

```
server.on("/on", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("ON hit.");
    String message;
    Serial.println(request->url());
    if (request->hasParam("device"))
    {
        message = request->getParam("device")->value();
    }
    else
    {
        message = " not specified";
    }
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "On, GET: " + message);
    Serial.print("Device ");
    Serial.println(message);
....
```

When sending in a request I get the out put, "Device not specified".

I take a look at the request-params() which gives me back a count of params that are in there and it's returning 1. I write this out:

```
server.on("/off", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    Serial.println("OFF hit.");
    String message;
    int params = request->params();
    Serial.printf("%d params sent in\n", params);
    for (int i = 0; i < params; i++)
    {
        AsyncWebParameter *p = request->getParam(i);
        if (p->isFile())
        {
            Serial.printf("_FILE[%s]: %s, size: %u", p->name().c_str(), p->value().c_str(), p->size());
        }
        else if (p->isPost())
        {
            Serial.printf("_POST[%s]: %s", p->name().c_str(), p->value().c_str());
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.printf("_GET[%s]: %s", p->name().c_str(), p->value().c_str());
        }
    }
    if (request->hasParam("device"))
    {
        message = request->getParam("device")->value();
    }
    else
    {
        message = "not specified";
    }
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "Off, GET: " + message);
    Serial.print("Device ");
    Serial.println(message);
```

and get the output now of

```
1 params sent in
_POST[device]: puddle
Device not specified
```

If I try to do something like request->getParam(0)->value().c_str()
I get a stack dump of a bunch of hex values that I have no idea what it means: but it looks like a big fat error.

Comment: try `hasParam("device", true)`

Comment: usually params are for GET while POST has a separate interface

Comment: @Juraj that was it. Want to make an answer? Lol, feel pretty silly.

Comment: just in case, someone finds this snipplet: 
In addition to @Juraj (correct) answer: If you want to access this param you also have to inform the function, that you want the url parameters:
`message = request->getParam("device", true)->value();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For POST request the `hasParam` needs to know if you want to test the url parameters or `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters in body of the POST request. The second parameter of the `hasParam` is `boolean post` and it has default value `false`. Use `hasParam("device", true)`.